# Finding control in a asp.net panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

How can I find the controls from a panel using c#. Am using the below code to find the control. But it always return null.

My partial code is here:

```
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
ddl.ID = "ID" + i;
ddl.DataValueField = "fld_Head";
ddl.DataTextField = "fld_Head";
ddl.DataSource = DVS;
ddl.DataBind();
Panel1.Controls.Add(ddl);
Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("&nbsp;&nbsp;"));
```

Another Process Code :

```
if (DT.Rows.Count > 0)
{
  string head = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[i - 1]["fld_Head"]);
  if (head != "")
  {
    DropDownList Head = ((DropDownList)this.Panel1.FindControl("ID" + i));
                                Head.SelectedItem.Text = head;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you checked that the control actually exists in the panel? Check out the page source of your asp.net page. `FindControl` should work.

Comment: Yes, That control present in my page with id.

Comment: Are you trying to find the control after a postback?

Answer (score 3):

If you add a control dynamically to another container control as a child, it will not be available at the next post back in the same containers child controls collection. So what you must do is create the same control again, assing its properties and add to child controls collection again.

Answer (score 0):

```
Foreach Control c in Panel.Controls

    c.Name
    c.Id
    c.Whatever
```

Comment: While the method `FindControl` exists, enumerating all the controls in a panel is not necesarry. He could verify the existance of a control with a enumeration, but it's neither the proper way to find a control, neither a solution to his current problem. If `FindControl` does not find it, it won't be in the enumeration.

Comment: Thank you for educating me :) When I answered, the question stated "iterate through controls". Now it's edited and I look like a moron :)